# How do you create a hyperlink-comment of a locally saved file- PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-10

Looking for something like this:

# http://file///path/to/example.png

or

# http://localhost/path/to/example.pdf

Any work arounds would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. This was of great help:

https://serverfault.com/a/126090

So I had to configure a server. I'm sure there are a ton of ways of doing this, but windows comes with it's own IIS (Internet information Services). Also, I had to create a virtual directory to be able to browse my files.

And now with this as a comment in my code:

# http://localhost/path/to/example.pdf

I can reference documentation with ease.

---

**Steps to setup IIS:**

1. Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features
2. Select "Turn Windows features on or off" in the side bar
3. Enable "Internet information Services"
4. Open IIS app
5. Create "website" in left panel. point to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot"
6. Right click on new website and add virtual directory. point to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot"
7. After creation, right click on it and select "Convert to Application"
8. Look for "Directory Browsing" and enable it in in right side panel

**CATCH**: You have to work out of this - "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" directory from now on.